# Need to calculate running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands

I have data like below and I need to somewhat generate running total but not really. When value changes from Green to either (Yellow or Red) then 1 for all rows until it changes again from Green to either Red or Yellow then 2 for all rows until it changes.

I think I can use `lag` function to check the previous row vs the current row but not sure how I can get this output.

| value | output |
| --- | --- |
| Black | 0 |
| Blue | 0 |
| Green | 0 |
| Yellow | 1 |
| Black | 1 |
| Green | 1 |
| Red | 2 |
| Black | 2 |
| Blue | 2 |
| Green | 2 |
| Green | 2 |
| Yellow | 3 |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Why not have a go and see how you get on, have a play with lag, read up on gaps-and-islands and have a go? You might surprise yourself.

Comment: How would you order the rows? Rememer SQL tales are unordered sets unless you use `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands variant. Assuming that you have a column to order the records, say `id`, we can identify the transitions with a `lag` and a window `sum`:

```
select id, val,
    sum(case when lag_val = 'Green' and val != 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) 
        over(order by id) grp
from (
    select t.*, lag(val, 1, val) over(order by id) lag_val
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

| id | val | grp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Black | 0 |
| 2 | Blue | 0 |
| 3 | Green | 0 |
| 4 | Yellow | 1 |
| 5 | Black | 1 |
| 6 | Green | 1 |
| 7 | Red | 2 |
| 8 | Black | 2 |
| 9 | Blue | 2 |
| 10 | Green | 2 |
| 11 | Green | 2 |
| 12 | Yellow | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1NA5ZNtn)

Comment: .. When value changes from Green to either Yellow or Red

Comment: It’s the same result..`lag_val = 'Green' and val in ('Red', 'Yellow') then 1..`